# KineticJS: animation performance in Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, kineticjs

I'm running an animation using Kineticjs using the Animation module. Now I noticed there quite a big performance difference between Chrome and Firefox. Looking at the framerate I found the following results.

```
     Chrome    Firefox
avg:     50         50
min:     33         20
max:     56         75
```

As you can see, the variability of the framerate for FireFox is a lot bigger. The animation in Chrome is smooth (at least smooth enough), but the animation in Firefox is choppy every second or so, this happens when the framerate is very high or low.

Especially the high framerate spikes seem to ruin the appearance of a smooth animation.

Has anybody else experienced this behaviour? And is there a way to smooth the framerate out a bit more in Firefox?

Comment: I'm not familiar with KineticJS, however having used both Chrome and Firefox for a while I can say that all-around Chrome just handles animations much better that Firefox.

Comment: I have experienced that.  I don't know what the issue is with FF, but sometimes I just need to restart the browser or my computer and then it works really well for a while again.

Comment: Agreed.  FF gets "stutters" especially during high stress animations.

Comment: Is not related to KinecticJS. It's something much more general. For example vis.js or SIMILE timeline, feel much more choppy when  the user drags it on FireFox. Here is other example of it : http://elgreco.digibis.com/en/musobjects/timeline.html?busq_concept=53

Comment: I am making a Parallax site with Fixed canvas at BG and facing same but opposite problem: Chrome is having performance issue where firefox is Fine.

Answer (score 1):

**This could be due to browser tab architecture differences**, such as the fact that currently Google Chrome uses a separate process for each tab, so slow or bad code in one tab is far less able to affect code in another tab.  With Firefox tabs are run in the same process, so slow code on one tab can affect other tabs.

**This could also be due to browser performance differences**, meaning the implementation of DOM and Javascript APIs that you are using.

> is there a way to smooth the framerate out a bit more in Firefox?

You should try to find some causes for the difference in the framerate, process of elimination is probably the best path.

Try using the browsers with only one tab, and go through the list of apis used to see if there are performance differences for those.